# Отследить координаты клика мыши внутри div'a

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется div размером 400х400рх, находится он в отступe от верхнего края 100рх.

```
   <div style="width: 400px; height: 400px; margin-top: 100px" id="box">
   </div>
```

Далее, хочу написать слежку за координатами нажатия мыши конкретно внутри div'a. 
Сделал следующее:

```
  <script>
  box.onclick = function() {
  alert (event.pageX+':'+event.pageY);
  }            
  </script>
```

Координаты отслеживает, выводит, но счёт начинается не с левого верхнего угла div'a, а именно с угла страницы, как исправить?

Answer (score 3):

Надо отнять от координаты мышки с начала страницы координаты элемента.

Конечно, есть специальное свойство `offsetX` и `offsetY`, но они не кроссбраузерные.

```js
box.onclick = function() {
  console.log((event.pageX - box.offsetLeft) + ':' + (event.pageY - box.offsetTop));
}
```

```css
#box {
  margin: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```